# Cloud pixel filters for Sentinel-2 images

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, pixel, cloud-gis

I'm trying to perform a supervised land use classification for a region (Buenos Aires Delta) and a specific time period (between January and March 2017). I'm using Sentinel-2 images processed in GEE for the classification, but I'm unable to find cloud-free images for the given time period and region. Therefore, I tried two filtering options:

**Option A**:

Applied a cloud filter (1%) when calling the COPERNICUS collection.
Code:

```
var FechaInicio2 = '2017-01-01';

var FechaFin2 = '2017-3-18';

//Seleccionar bandas utilizadas para Sentinel-2

var bandasS2_invierno=['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B11'];

//Llamar colección y filtrar

var datasetS2_invierno = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED') 

              .filterDate(FechaInicio2,FechaFin2)

              .filterBounds(departamento_roi)

              .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 1))

              .select(bandasS2_invierno);
```

As a result, I was unable to obtain an image for much of the region:
[image: Delta 2017]

**Option B**

I used the following code to perform pixel-by-pixel filtering:

```
var bandasS2=['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B11'];

//Llamar colección y filtrar

var datasetS2_nub = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED') 

              .filterDate(FechaInicio,FechaFin)

              .filterBounds(departamento_roi);

              //.select(bandasS2);


var s2c = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY')

              .filterDate(FechaInicio,FechaFin)

              .filterBounds(departamento_roi);


// Define a collection filtering function.

function filterBoundsDate(imgCol, departamento_roi, FechaInicio, FechaFin) {

  return imgCol.filterBounds(departamento_roi).filterDate(FechaInicio, FechaFin);

}

// Define a function to join the two collections on their 'system:index'

// property. The 'propName' parameter is the name of the property that

// references the joined image.

function indexJoin(colA, colB, propName) {

  var joined = ee.ImageCollection(ee.Join.saveFirst(propName).apply({

    primary: colA,

    secondary: colB,

    condition: ee.Filter.equals(

        {leftField: 'system:index', rightField: 'system:index'})

  }));

  // Merge the bands of the joined image.

  return joined.map(function(image) {

    return image.addBands(ee.Image(image.get(propName)));

  });

}

// Define a function to create a cloud masking function.
function buildMaskFunction(cloudProb) {
  return function(img) {
    // Define clouds as pixels having greater than the given cloud probability.
    var cloud = img.select('probability').gt(ee.Image(cloudProb));

    // Apply the cloud mask to the image and return it.
    return img.updateMask(cloud.not());
  };
}

// Join the cloud probability collection to the TOA reflectance collection.

var withCloudProbability = indexJoin(datasetS2_nub, s2c, 'cloud_probability');

// Map the cloud masking function over the joined collection, select only the
// reflectance bands.

var maskClouds = buildMaskFunction(50);

var s2Masked = ee.ImageCollection(withCloudProbability.map(maskClouds))

                   .select(ee.List.sequence(0, 12));

// Calculate the median of overlapping pixels per band.

var median = s2Masked.median();

// Calculate the difference between each image and the median.

var difFromMedian = s2Masked.map(function(img) {

  var dif = ee.Image(img).subtract(median).pow(ee.Image.constant(2));

  return dif.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()).addBands(img).copyProperties(img, [

    'system:time_start'

  ]);

});

// Generate a composite image by selecting the pixel that is closest to the
// median.

var bandNames = difFromMedian.first().bandNames();

var bandPositions = ee.List.sequence(1, bandNames.length().subtract(1));

var mosaic = difFromMedian.reduce(ee.Reducer.min(bandNames.length()))

                 .select(bandPositions, bandNames.slice(1))

                 .clipToCollection(departamento_roi);

                 
Map.addLayer(

    mosaic, {bands: ['B8', 'B11', 'B3'], min:[49.5], max:[3241]}, 'S2 mosaic');
```

With the last code, I encountered the following issues:

Issue 1: There are strips without pixels that are not caused by cloud cover, but rather they seem to be the joining points between two consecutive Sentinel-2 images.

Issue 2: There are still clouds present. I imagine that this issue is not solvable.

Issue 3: It doesn't filter out the shadows generated by clouds."

[image: Problemas]

Is there any improved code or a way to improve mine?

Comment: Have you tried using a reducer? It might be a useful to obtain a median composite of certain period